# Fix sticky/tight/jamming wooden drawer

Tags: wood, drawers

I got a new all beech wooden chest of drawers (lowboy) second hand. It has some smaller and some wider drawer,s all of them jamming on opening and closing.
I know they should slide nice and smooth if they where fabricated accurate to measurement, only they are not.

What would be an easy way to get them working properly? I would be very interrested in different methods, especially ones that not interfere with  the substance of the wood, and which last.

Comment: d.gorge make that an answer I was going to post the same. Candle wax is what I have used for wood slides for many decades works and won't harm the wood.+

Comment: Sounds like a manufacturing defect; can you get service and/or return it?

Comment: It's second hand, cannot return.

Comment: @d.george and Ed Beal: Candle wax is what I know already. Please make it an answer instead of a comment so that others can rate it and you get credit!